# getSharedPreferences() is not recognized in the class extended from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I like to use SharedPreferences in the class extended from BroadcastReceiver. But this method `getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);` is not recognized. How can I retrieve `SharedPreferences` in the `BroadcastReceiver` class?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need a `Context` to retrieve the `SharedPreferences`. `onReceive` gives you the context

Comment: Yeah, if inside the onReceive method I can use context from the onReceive method. But it is in another method.

Comment: you can always keep a reference . You can, for instance, store in a class variable. Or you can better store the SharedPreferences in a class variable

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPreferences` is a method of `Context`, your `activity` extends `Context` that is why you can use it as is.

If you want to use it somewhere else, you need a context. The easiest way is provided in this answer

[Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Step 1 : You add a class in AndroidManifest.xml

Step 2 : You create your class this way

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context _context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _context = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return _context;
    }
}
```

Step 3 : Whenever you need something with a context you do : `App.getContext()`

in your case `App.getContext().getSharedPreferences()`